# Consulta sobre ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version-control, rubygems

undefined method `password_digest=' for #User:0x000055ca88d757a0 Did you mean? password_digest
Extracted source (around line #432):

```
  else
    match = matched_attribute_method(method.to_s)
    match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
  end
end
ruby2_keywords(:method_missing) if respond_to?(:ruby2_keywords, true)
```

ruby -v 2.5.3 y rails 6.0.3 :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the Devise gem for user authentication.
The error is that in the database as such the field is password_digest, but to create a new user you must pass the parameter only as **password**, not as password_digest.

If you don't solve it with that, it's very helpful include details like What triggers the error ?, and pieces of the code that involve the action.